# Why am I having problems using multiple toggles?

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade, slide

On my website, if you click a certain button, it toggles a fadeToggle, and slideToggle simultaneously . If you click a different button, does the exact same, but with different content. But if you press both, they end up out of sync. One is toggled, another is not.

Press information and THEN clients, it messes the toggles up. They become out of sync.

Is there a way to avoid this overlap?

Here is the jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function(){

        $('#stop').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); });

         $('#information').click(function() {
   $("#projectwrap").slideToggle('slow'); 
   $("#us").fadeToggle('slow');
   });

      $('#clients').click(function() {
   $("#projectwrap").slideToggle('slow'); 
   $("ul").fadeToggle('slow');
   });


});
</script>
```

If you're confused, so am I!

Comment: Can you give a clear description of what you would like to happen?

Comment: I couldn't open your website, please post the related markup instead of linking to an external page. It sounds that your have 2 elements with the same IDs, am I right?

Comment: use `hide()` and `show()` with the middle text, to avoid the mess

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/irutiz/5/edit)*

The logical problem is that you're toggling `#projectwrap` on both `#information` and `#clients` click! And what makes no sense at all is that you cannot click any more on the `#title` element to review the main content. And that is a bad *UX* (User Experience).

You should use this HTML structure:
Add a class `.toggler` to all your clickable elements and toggle-state on the inner element `.content` !

```
<div id="stop"> 
 
  <div id="clients">
    <h2 class="toggler">clients</h2>
    <div class="content" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="projectwrap">
    <h1 class="toggler">projectwrap</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <p>text here.........</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="information">
    <h2 class="toggler">info</h2>
    <div class="content" style="display:none;">
       about us..........
     </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

now we will search with jQuery for the clickable `.next('.content')` element!

jQuery:

```
$('#stop').click(function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
});
   
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  var $nextContent = $(this).next('.content');
  var nextContIsHidden = $nextContent.is(':hidden');
  if(nextContIsHidden){
    $('.content:visible').slideUp('slow'); // hide all visible
    $nextContent.slideDown('slow');    
  }else{                          // if we're clicking the title of the visible one
    $nextContent.slideUp('slow'); // if is already visible hide it
    $('#projectwrap .content').slideDown('slow'); // and slide the main content
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be an exact but long winded version of his.. Your replacing his slideToggle with a call to a function that does what slideToggle does...